# Best way to parse complicated XML with Perl?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have to parse several XML files using Perl and store variables in a hash. I'd like to filter through certain attributes if possible.  Later in my code I pull data from the hash and insert into a database.

I have been using [`XML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser) but I would prefer to parse into a hash rather than handle each tag as it encountered. Any suggestions?

I'd like to skip any path that has the attribute `kind="dir"`.  I need the author, date, msg, and the filetypes (the file extensions) of the paths.  The `<path>` tags can have any number and are either of `kind` "file" or "dir".  There can also be multiple `<logentry>` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
    <logentry revision="3989">
        <author>cergyl</author>
        <date>2013-07-19T05:31:01.212620Z</date>
        <paths>
            <path action="M" kind="dir">/team.admin/trunk/auth.conf</path>
        </paths>
        <path action="M" kind="file">/team.admin/trunk/file.cpp</path>
        <msg>Whitespace change to verify repository synchronization</msg>
    </logentry>
</log>
```

```
my $XML_Parser = XML::Parser->new(
                                  Handlers => {
                                                 Start   => \&hdl_xml_tag_start,
                                                 End     => \&hdl_xml_tag_end,
                                                 Char    => \&hdl_xml_nonmarkup_char,
                                                 Default => \&hdl_xml_default
                                               }
                                 );

# This event is generated when an XML start tag is recognized. Parser is an XML::Parser::Expat instance.
sub hdl_xml_tag_start
{
    my ( $parser, $element, %attributes ) = @_;
    $attributes{ '_str' } = "$element:";
    $XML_Attributes_Hash_Ref = \%attributes;
    return;
}

# This event is generated when an XML end tag is recognized. Note that an XML empty tag (<foo/>) generates both a start and an end event.
sub hdl_xml_tag_end
{
    my ( $parser, $element ) = @_;

    #format_message($XML_Attributes_Hash_Ref);
    format_svn_history( $XML_Attributes_Hash_Ref );
    return;
}


# This event is generated when non-markup is recognized. The non-markup sequence of characters is in String.
# A single non-markup sequence of characters may generate multiple calls to this handler.
sub hdl_xml_nonmarkup_char
{
    my ( $parser, $string ) = @_;
    $XML_Attributes_Hash_Ref->{ '_str' } .= $string;
    return;
}

#This is called for any characters that don't have a registered handler.
sub hdl_xml_default { return; }
```

Comment: Why isn't `XML::Parser` working for you?

Comment: I really like XML::Twig, not least because it lets me `purge` as I go to save memory footprint.

Comment: @friedo, I edited my question.  It works, but I would prefer to take the whole thing in at once in as a hash.

Comment: XML::Parser is a low level parse. I agree with your desire to move away from it. However, I recommend against moving to a parser that produces a hash. They are the hardest ones to use. I use XML::LibXML (very fast, very powerful, supports any XML), but XML::Twig is also popular (especially if your XML file is a long list of records).

Comment: the structure of your XML is quite confusing. A single `logentry` is not enough to get an idea of what other entries may look like. Do you want to entirely ignore all the `paths` elements and only use the `path` found right before `msg`? Is there always a single one of those `path` elements? It's hard to help you without more information

Comment: What have you written? And what are the problems you have encountered?

Comment: If you want help then you must explain yourself much better. *"store variables in a hash"* and *"filter through certain attributes if possible"* don't really help at all. Please show an example of the resultant hash you would like to see, and what you mean by *"filter through certain attributes"*. Please *don't* ask for a hash just because you have seen or heard of a module that will process XML to a hash. The obvious one that does that is a minefield and should be avoided. Choose a data representation that is best for what you want to do with the data after it has been read.

Comment: @Busch: You say, *"It works, but I would prefer to take the whole thing in at once in as a hash"* But you give us nothing but vague ideals to work with. You need to either specify your requirement completely or post your existing code somewhere - perhaps on Stack Exchange [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I apologize. I have added additional content to help clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the limited information you have offered it is hard to write a comprehensive solution, but here is something that uses [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) to process the XML data you have shown and display all (one) `path` elements that don't have a `kind` attribute equal to `dir`.

[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) is also a very high quality module based on the C-coded [libxml2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxml2)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $parser = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => {
    path => \&path_handler,
  }
);

$parser->parse(*DATA);

sub path_handler {
  my ($twig, $path) = @_;
  return if $path->att('kind') eq 'dir';
  print $path->text, "\n";
}


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
    <logentry revision="3989">
        <author>cergyl</author>
        <date>2013-07-19T05:31:01.212620Z</date>
        <paths>
            <path action="M" kind="dir">/team.admin/trunk/auth.conf</path>
        </paths>
        <path action="M" kind="file">/team.admin/trunk/file.cpp</path>
        <msg>Whitespace change to verify repository synchronization</msg>
    </logentry>
</log>
```

**output**

```
/team.admin/trunk/file.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the XML::DOM::Parser from [XML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~tjmather/XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm).  But I use XML::Twig to pretty print them.

`my $xp = XML::DOM::Parser->new();
  my $doc = $xp->parse("<xml></xml>");
  $doc->dispose();
  my $doc = $xp->parsefile("file.xml");
  $doc->dispose();
  // Pretty Print My poorly formatted xml doc
  my $xpp = XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented');
  $xpp->parse("<xml></xml>");
  $xpp->print();`